# Why does an indexed DELETE take so long?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-delete

This DELETE (among many others) is taking very long. The table has ~1M rows, but they are properly indexed by `updatedAt` and there are only ~5k rows to delete:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Users" where "_etl" = true and "updatedAt" >= '2015-01-15 15:01:10.454-05'
```

> 5163

Here's the EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN DELETE FROM "Users" where "_etl" = true and "updatedAt" >= '2015-01-15 15:01:10.454-05'

Delete on "Users"  (cost=0.42..23581.27 rows=38909 width=6)
  ->  Index Scan using user_updatedat_etl_index on "Users"  (cost=0.42..23581.27 rows=38909 width=6)
        Index Cond: ("updatedAt" >= '2015-01-15 15:01:10.454-05'::timestamp with time zone)
        Filter: _etl
```

I'm not sure, but perhaps it's because the `Users` table has many foreign keys? I've already been waiting ~30 minutes for this `DELETE` to finish and can't think of a legitimate reason this should take so long.

Comment: Yes, it will need to run 5163 queries on each child table. If one of these tables lacks an index on the FK field, this could take a while. It will also try to lock any child records it finds - even for `RESTRICT` and `NO ACTION` constraints - so it could potentially be blocked by another session.

Comment: @NickBarnes Right, so I've now added indexes on all foreign keys referencing `Users` and am not using any other database connections. I'll try another batch of 7465 rows and see if that helps.

Comment: Check pg_stat_activity to see if your query is waiting for a lock to be released.

Comment: It was still very slow, and there are no active queries. Do I need to rebuild the new indexes I made on the foreign keys?

Comment: Ok, this one was pretty fast. Not sure why `Users` is so slow: `DELETE FROM "ActivityLogs" where "updatedAt" > '2015-01-14 19:10:54.306-05' Affected rows : 45236, Time: 6.27sec`

Comment: Any `DELETE` triggers on `Users`?